# Use mutate and if else function in loop with vectors as index

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, indexing, dplyr

I am attempting to a use a character vector as an index in a loop that runs through several mutate and if esle conditions. The code I am posting below is a simplified version of code I working through and I am using `var <- "pr_cnt"`  instead of a character vector. The issue I am having is getting mutate to recognize the column name. The code runs in its current form but produces incorrect values of NA. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
# Create test data.frame
test <- data.frame(numfish = c(1:10),
               Hrsfished = runif(n = 10, min = 2, max = 8),
               pr_cnt = runif(n = 10, min = 12, max = 20),
               dfished = rep(12, times = 10),
               DF = c(41:50))
#Run simplified for loop using var <- "pr_cnt" in ifelse statement
for(i in 1:1){
  var <- "pr_cnt"
  m<- mutate(test, dummy = ifelse(Hrsfished < pr_cnt, .data[[var]]/2), 0)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest this approach:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
# Create test data.frame
test <- data.frame(numfish = c(1:10),
                   Hrsfished = runif(n = 10, min = 2, max = 8),
                   pr_cnt = runif(n = 10, min = 12, max = 20),
                   dfished = rep(12, times = 10),
                   DF = c(41:50))
#Run simplified for loop using var <- "pr_cnt" in ifelse statement
for(i in 1:1){
  var <- "pr_cnt"
  m<- test %>% mutate(dummy = ifelse(Hrsfished < pr_cnt, .[[var]]/2, 0))
}
```

Output:

```
   numfish Hrsfished   pr_cnt dfished DF    dummy
1        1  7.165499 18.72514      12 41 9.362572
2        2  6.492989 12.03126      12 42 6.015629
3        3  6.279756 19.37658      12 43 9.688288
4        4  3.517261 14.32274      12 44 7.161372
5        5  2.295499 17.65783      12 45 8.828916
6        6  3.959048 13.18265      12 46 6.591327
7        7  4.850488 14.04858      12 47 7.024292
8        8  6.714393 14.51119      12 48 7.255597
9        9  7.968184 13.73512      12 49 6.867558
10      10  2.201459 19.49538      12 50 9.747691
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt and helpful response. Changing `.data[[]]` to `.[[]]` fixed my problem.

Comment: @Winn Fantastic, if you think this answer was helpful, you could accept it by clicking the tick on the left side of this answer. It is up to you :)